# Circumferencial waves on a cylinder/sphere

Tags: wave-propagation, spherical-harmonics

I was wondering how we can introduce $e^{ik.x}$ terms associated with circumferencially propagating waves? In this case $\hat{e}_\theta$ is the direction of wave propagation. However, I was not able to express the exponent  of exponential using a dot product because of polar coordinates. How can we introduce this dot product? Can spherical harmonics or Fourier transform help here?

Comment: Polar coordinates don't matter. You can express your $k$ and $x$ vectors in whatever basis you want and evaluate the dot products between the basis vectors. For starters, try expressing $\hat{e}_\theta$ in the cartesian unit vector basis.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/11389/9667)?

Comment: I don't think you can write this term in the form you want. Could you provide more detail on why you're trying to do this?